# How to concat() multiple array's and check if values already exist

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

i concat multiple Arrays to one Array. This works well

```
this.facetsLocations = [].concat(
                response.facets['134_locations'].terms,
                response.facets['135_locations'].terms
              );
```

But the Output ist not what i want. As you can see i have same terms like "deutschland", count: 6
"deutschland", count: 4 and so on.

the result should be one "deutschland", count 10
i want to check if the value already exists and add the count values.

```
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {term: "deutschland", count: 6}
1: {term: "basel", count: 3}
2: {term: "osteuropa", count: 2}
3: {term: "österreich", count: 1}
4: {term: "ungarn", count: 1}
5: {term: "schweiz", count: 1}
6: {term: "basel", count: 5}
7: {term: "deutschland", count: 4}
8: {term: "österreich", count: 1}
9: {term: "ungarn", count: 1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `concat()` function only concatenates two arrays, i.e. returns a new array that contains all elements from first and second (and more) arrays. It does not do anything else, and it does not concern itself with contents of merging arrays, this should be your application's logic.

One way to achieve what you need is to use `reduce()` instead of `concat()`, like so:

```
// This is pretty much the same as doing concatenation your way
const terms = [
  ...response.facets['134_locations'].terms,
  ...response.facets['135_locations'].terms,
];

// using reducer on all terms
this.facetsLocations = Object.values(terms.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (typeof acc[item.term] === 'undefined') {
    // set default value for each term as 0
    acc[item.term] = item;
  } else {
    // add to total count of each term
    acc[item.term].count += item.count;

    // potentially add logic to handle changing "selected" too...
  }

  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Comment: Short Question. The Output is a little bit diffrent from the Original Source. How to avoid it. From {term: "deutschland", count: 6, selected: false} . to basel: 10
deutschland: 10
osteuropa: 3 . .... i need the term, count and selected description

Comment: @Fonty I have edited my response to return an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` to find all the object with your `term` value and then using `array#reduce` sum it up

```js
let data = [{term: "deutschland", count: 6},{term: "basel", count: 3},{term: "osteuropa", count: 2},{term: "österreich", count: 1},{term: "ungarn", count: 1},{term: "schweiz", count: 1},{term: "basel", count: 5},{term: "deutschland", count: 4},{term: "österreich", count: 1},{term: "ungarn", count: 1}],
    term = "deutschland",
    result = {term, count : data.filter(o => o.term === term)
                                .reduce((sum, {count}) => sum += count, 0)};
console.log(result);
```

You can just use `array#reduce` to sum all the count for a single `term`.

```js
let data = [{term: "deutschland", count: 6},{term: "basel", count: 3},{term: "osteuropa", count: 2},{term: "österreich", count: 1},{term: "ungarn", count: 1},{term: "schweiz", count: 1},{term: "basel", count: 5},{term: "deutschland", count: 4},{term: "österreich", count: 1},{term: "ungarn", count: 1}],
    term = "deutschland",
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
      if(term === o.term) {
        r.count += o.count;
      }
      return r;
    },{term, count : 0});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use lodash

```
  var data = [
{ term: "deutschland", count: 6 },
{ term: "basel", count: 3 },
{ term: "osteuropa", count: 2 },
{ term: "österreich", count: 1 },
{ term: "ungarn", count: 1 },
{ term: "schweiz", count: 1 },
{ term: "basel", count: 5 },
{ term: "deutschland", count: 4 },
{ term: "österreich", count: 1 },
{ term: "ungarn", count: 1 }


]

  let groupped = (_.groupBy(this.data, "term"));

    let view = Object.keys(groupped).map((k) => {
      return {
        term: k,
        count: groupped[k].length
      }
    })

    console.log(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method `concatObject` like this

```js
var objA = {term: "deutschland", count: 6}
var objB = {term: "deutschland", count: 4}
function concatObject(objA, objB){
obj = Object.keys(objA).concat(Object.keys(objB))
  .reduce(function(obj, k) {
  
    obj[k] = (objA[k] || 0) + (objB[k] || 0);
  
    return obj;
  
  }, {})
//  console.log(obj);
return obj;
 }
 
 var res = concatObject(objA, objB);
 console.log(res);
```